# Functional Style Comparator using Java 8

Tags: java, comparator, functional-interface

Hello guys let me make me clear first I have not done this code. I found this from internet and it does better and clean sorting using comparator as being new to java 8 functional style programming I wonder how the process flow in the given code. Can please someone explain me how this code is working. Thanks :)

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class EmployeeInfoBest {
    static enum SortMethod {BYNAME, BYSALARY};
    final Function<Employee, String> byName = e -> e.getName();
    final Function<Employee, Integer> bySalary = e -> e.getSalary();

    final static class Pair<S,T> {
        Pair(S f, T t) {
            first = f;
            second = t;
        }
        S first;
        T second;
    }

    final Pair<Function,Function> byNamePair
      = new Pair<>(byName, bySalary);
    final Pair<Function,Function> bySalaryPair
      = new Pair<>(bySalary, byName);

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    final HashMap<SortMethod, Pair<Function,Function>> sortDiscriminator =
      new HashMap<SortMethod, Pair<Function,Function>>() {
        {
                put(SortMethod.BYNAME, byNamePair);
                put(SortMethod.BYSALARY, bySalaryPair);
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sort(List<Employee> emps, final SortMethod method) {
        Collections.sort(emps, 
                Comparator.comparing(sortDiscriminator.get(method).first)
                          .thenComparing(sortDiscriminator.get(method).second));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
        emps.add(new Employee("Joe", 100000));
        emps.add(new Employee("Tim", 50000));
        emps.add(new Employee("Andy", 60000));
        EmployeeInfoBest ei = new EmployeeInfoBest();
        ei.sort(emps, EmployeeInfoBest.SortMethod.BYNAME);
        System.out.println(emps);
        //same instance
        ei.sort(emps, EmployeeInfoBest.SortMethod.BYSALARY);
        System.out.println(emps);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Which part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: This seems...significantly overly complicated.  The whole thing could be one line: `emps.sort((method == BYNAME) ? comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getSalary) : comparing(Employee::getSalary).thenComparing(Employee::getName))`.

Comment: I found difficulty in understanding the hashmap i.e. sortDiscriminator part. The question is to sort the employee with two criteria one with the byName first and another is bySalary criteria

Comment: according to question "Eliminate the branching logic by defining a HashMap, together with a Pair class"

Comment: This is not very good code. This whole part about setting up Pairs of comparators is very roundabout. Can be much more straightforward (see @LouisWasserman's comment), even if it is supposed to be configurable at runtime.